# How to plot multiple bars?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Good evening
I am new to this forum and I am not a developer. However, I am learning how to analyze data as I work in a hospital with a research unit. 
Right now I am stuck with a plot bar I am trying to create:
I would like to analyze the symptoms of patients that are grading from 1 to 4 and compare the symptoms at different times: "baseline", "one month", "six months", "one year", "two years"
I manage to create plot bar with only one time (baseline or one year for example) but can't merge them all:

```
baseline[["symp_nyha"]].plot(kind="hist", bins=[0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5], rwidth=0.8)
one_year[["symp_nyha"]].plot(kind="hist", bins=[0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5], rwidth=0.8)
plt.show()
```

of course, it shows me two plots.

Can you help me?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-deep')

x = np.random.normal(1, 2, 5000) # Baseline values as list like: [3,2,1, ...]
y = np.random.normal(-1, 3, 2000) # one_year values as list like: [2,3,4, ...]
bins = [0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5, 4.5]

plt.hist([x, y], bins, label=['baseline', 'one_year'])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

If you synchronize baseline and one_year values ​​to X and Y values ​​as a list. You can get the histogram that the two are together.

[Histogram According to X and Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8YD3.png)

Comment: Thank you so much, it works well ! and I can add several bars. Can you also tell me how to put legends ? I would like each bar to be legend as "baseline" or "one_year"?